# Access private images with <img> tag in REST with Spring security & JWT

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, oauth

**Current Scenario**

A Spring project have REST API's protected using Spring Security and JWT. These API's produces JSON response. A `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is implemented for validating JWT sent in `Authorization` header. Both authenticated and unauthenticated API's are working as intended.

**Requirement**

Now I need to sent an image in HTTP response for logged in user.

**Solution1**

Sent a `byte[]`, representing the image as the *value* to an "image" *key* along with other information.
But, this may take some time for the full JSON response, if the image is large.

**Solution2**

Sent a link as the *value* to an "image" *key* along with other information. The client can assign `<img src=the_link>`, which will supposed to fetch the large image in a separate request. Then create a request with `@RequestMapping`, corresponding to that link, which produces a `byte[]`.

**My Problem**

I prefer Solution2. But it will produce `UNAUTHORIZED` exception as there is no valid `Authorization` token. Also, this API must be authenticated.

After some search, found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725054/protecting-image-resources-with-oauth2-bearer-tokens), which is the same as my requirement. The accepted answer says,

> The OAuth Bearer Token spec supports sending the token as a query parameter.

**Is this what I must do?**

- In my Spring filter, get JWT from `Authorization` header, if it is
  empty, get it from `request.getParameter()`
- In JSON response of first
  API, send `"image":"http://ip/getImage?token=dbscsbCXV"`
- Create an API `@GetMapping("getImage") byte[] getImage()`

Or is there any better approach?
Please guide me.

Answer (score 9):

Your suggestion to include the token in seems to be okay, if you:

- Use HTTPS for your server, otherwise the JWT token in the request headers are expose (same goes for the Authorization headers).
- Don't mind the image URL no longer working, when the token changes

---

Another approach may be to generate a random key with sufficient entropy (eg. combine 3 UUID's into a single string) and store this along with your Image entity, returning it from your REST services, eg:

```
https://ip/images/824b6854-edcc-11e6-bc64-92361f0026713567fef0-549a-4cdb-9264-5e15166dfd6f/the-file-name.pdf
```

Make sure you disable the Spring security filter for these "public" paths.

Advantages of this approach:

- No need to check authentication for this resource
- (if the image doesn't change alot) You can have this cached or serve the content through CDN, not hitting your servers every time for just streaming images.
- URL will keep working, even if JWT token for auth changes

You might think this is less secure than the using a per-call authentication, but if the ID's have enough entropy, it's waterproof. Facebook also uses this concept  (https://www.quora.com/Are-Facebook-pictures-really-private-and-are-they-hosted-on-Facebook-servers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security)

Comment: Thanks @FrederikHeremans. Will come back after trying out your suggestions and refering the links.